# Am I creating the relational links correctly? (Entity Framework)

Tags: .net, entity-framework-core, relational-database

I have a class `Organization` whose data cannot be overwritten. Organizations are read-only and used as links.

I have a `User` class that can be overwritten. In it, the administrator sets up links to available organizations.

Due to the fact that one user has many organizations available, I cannot directly link to the organization directly in the user class:

```
class user 
{
    public Organization AllowOrganization { get; set; } // no
}
```

Due to the fact that I do not have the ability to overwrite the properties of organizations, I create an intermediate class:

```
public class User
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public ICollection<AllowedItem> AllowedItems { get; set; } // Attention
}

public class AllowedItem
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public User Owner { get; set; }
    public Organization Item { get; set; }
}
```

This will work, but getting a list of available organizations will be difficult. What ways do you see?

Comment: This sounds more like many-to-many relationship (user has many organizations and organization has many users). So just create and configure standard join (linking) table. And if you are using EF Core 5.0+, you could even make it implicit and just add 2 collection navigation properties to User and Organization. This won't change their tables. See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/relationships?tabs=fluent-api%2Cfluent-api-simple-key%2Csimple-key#many-to-many

Comment: I did so, thanks. I have EF3.1, so I created the class (table) explicitly. It works.